# Bean object must not be null in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
OptionsTag    E org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag Bean object must not be null
                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bean object must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setWrappedInstance(BeanWrapperImpl.java:213)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setWrappedInstance(BeanWrapperImpl.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.<init>(BeanWrapperImpl.java:152)
at org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessorFactory.java:37)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionWriter.doRenderFromCollection(OptionWriter.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionWriter.renderFromCollection(OptionWriter.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionWriter.writeOptions(OptionWriter.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag.writeTagContent(OptionsTag.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
at com.ibm._jsp._searchNAV._jspx_meth_form_options_0(_searchNAV.java:262)
at com.ibm._jsp._searchNAV._jspx_meth_form_select_0(_searchNAV.java:304)
at com.ibm._jsp._searchNAV._jspx_meth_form_form_0(_searchNAV.java:442)
```

I am getting above error message, which I have not seen before . please help me in this regard.

Comment: I am getting above error message spring mvc application , which i have not seen before . please help me in this regard.

Comment: Some context for your stack trace helps people answer...I can guess at the answer but it's better to have more info...

Comment: RequestContextAwareTag doStartTag - is this some taglib tag that references a spring bean that is not there perhaps? -> OptionsTag.writeTagContent - maybe the options tag ?

Comment: My guess is that you have an options tag referencing a collection (doRenderFromCollection) where one of the items in the collection is null.

Comment: Where you are getting this error? could you please past code snippet also? If I am not wrong you have some null object set in controller and you have a view(may be JSP) on which you have the same object as form backing object and since it is null you are getting followwing error. Post your controller method and jsp code

Comment: @All : Thanks u all for helping to resolve the issue. The issue was , there was a null value in database and Iam retriving all the values from table . And simply sent that List to set jsp select box  and trying to render with help of JSTL. Unfortunatley JSTL was unable to render the database null to select box of JSP.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error when saving an entity on a JPA repository. It turned out it was simply the object I was passing that was null...